# imposm: importing route relations as single lines

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, imposm

I am trying to create a postgresql table with route relations where each route relation is one long multilinestring (basically replicating the result you get when querying for route relations with overpass).

I created a `relation` and `relation_member` table following the steps described here: [imposm.org/../relations](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm3/latest/relations.html#other-relations) but I am having trouble joining the geometries from the `relation_member`  to the `relation` table.

First I added a geometry column with `alter table RELATIONS add geometry geometry`and then joined the tables with `SELECT * FROM RELATION_MEMBERS JOIN RELATIONS ON RELATIONS.osm_id = RELATION_MEMBERS.osm_id` but the resulting table has invalid geometries.

What am I doing wrong?
(complete postgresql/imposm newbie)